# win32api.dll Missing

Tags: windows, python, dll

I am trying to start a Buildbot Buildslave on a Windows XP virtual machine:

```
python buildbot start .

ImportError: No module named win32api.
```

Google tells me that win32api is win32api.dll. I downloaded the file from www.dll-files.com and followed the guide found on that site (http://www.dll-files.com/unzip.php). When I try to run regsvr32 win32api.dll, it tells me that the specified module could not be found.

tl;dr - Where do I put win32api.dll so Windows will install it? Am I trying to use the wrong file? (using python version 2.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Twisted and pywin32 installed alongside Python? Buildbot requires all three on Windows. Unfortunately, the Buildbot manual doesn't appear to mention pywin32. More information can be found on [the Buildbot wiki](http://buildbot.net/trac/wiki/RunningBuildbotOnWindows) and [the Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildbotOnWindows).

Answer (score 0):

If you go to a command prompt and type "echo %pythonpath%" (without the quotes), does it give you a file path to python?

It sounds like maybe the environment variable for python is missing.

If it is, you can go under Control Panel->System->Advanced, click Environment Variables, click New, enter PYTHONPATH, then enter the path to the python lib folder (c:\python26\lib or whatever). You might also want to add that same path to your PATH environment variable.